# Dynamic URLS with laravel resource route, dont redirect

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Im trying to setup a simple resource controller to Pages/Editor/Index and Pages/Editor/Show,

I am showing each row in the database on the index page but when i click the Link i get this error and i dont even get redirected.

**Error 1**
failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

**Error 2**
editor:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/Pages/Editor/Show.vue

how is that even possible when the link directly states href="`/editor/{configuration.id}`">

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Configuration;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class EditorController extends Controller
{
        public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $configurations = Configuration::all();
        return Inertia::render('Editor/Index', [
            'configurations' => $configurations, // Pass the data to the Inertia response           
        ]);
    }

    public function show(Configuration $configuration)
    {

        return inertia('Editor/Show', [
            'configuration' => $configuration
        ]);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('editor', EditorController::class);
```

Editor/Index

```
<template>
    <div v-for="configuration in configurations">
        <Link :href="`/editor/{configuration.id}`">
        {{ configuration.id }}
        {{ configuration.identifier }}
        </Link>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

export default {

    name: "App",
    components: {
        configurator,
    },
    props: {
        configurations: Object,
    },
};
</script>
```

Editor/Show

```
<template>
    <p>SHOW ME</p>
    {{ configuration.id }}
</template>

<script setup>

defineProps({
    configuration: Object
})


</script>
```